# Css Issue after webPack updating

Tags: css, webpack, delay

I have update WebPack to v4.17 .but I have delay on website loading with this error on console :

> Refused to apply style from 'https://.../stylesheets/application.css'
>   because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME
>   type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.

what Should I do ??

Comment: If you are using `webpack-dev-server`, then all non matching routes will point back to index.html (might depend on your html5 history setting). So if you have specified the wrong path to `application.css` then you are likely to get the same error, so I would investigate that first. (to find out quickly, just inspect the network-request in your browsers webtools, click the preview tab and if you see content from your index.html then you know your css-filepath is wrong.

Comment: Or even easier, go to `https://.../stylesheets/application.css` in your browser and see if there is html or css.